# Maximize the area of ​a triangle by differential

Tags: calculus, optimization, triangles, differential

Two sides of a triangle have lengths "a" and "b" and the angle between them is "θ". What value of "θ" will maximize the area of ​​the triangle?
pd. sorry my bad english.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: What kind of triangle?

Comment: the problem I have is formulating the function to maximize but I am not very clear about what it is.

Comment: It is not specified what type of triangle in the question

Comment: Are you aware of the sined area formula?

Comment: Note that the area of a general triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin{C}$. This formula will yield its maximum value when $\sin{C}$=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of the triangle is $S=\frac{ab}{2}\sin\theta$. The maximum value for $\sin\theta$ is 1, then the angle that maximize the area is $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the area will be $S_{max}=\frac{ab}{2}$.